# Two-dimensional table first char

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I got

```
String table[][]= new String [i][j];
Scanner insertN = new Scanner(System.in);
int N= insertN.nextInt ();

table[i][j]="-----";
int number1=1;
int number2=2;
```

How can I get from first to n char ("-") and replace it with number(1)

if first N is 2 - program write in table 11---.
and if second N is 2 - program write in table 1122-

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: If i insert n=3, table[i][j]=111-- first 3 char change from (-) to 1

Comment: I would recommend to frame the question properly the first time.
Your every edit has completely changed the meaning of question
Prepared my answers twice, had to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String table[][] = new String[i][j];
table[i][j] "-----";
Scanner insertN = new Scanner(System.in);
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 2;

int N = insertN.nextInt();
int total = N;

//build a temporary string containing as many '1's as indicated by n
String tmp = "";
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) tmp = tmp + number1;

N = insertN.nextInt();
total = total + N;
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) tmp = tmp + number2;

//replace the original string with the '1's and the substring of table[i][j]
//starting at position n and continuing to the end
table[i][j] = tmp + table[i][j].substring(total, table[i][j].length());
```